# Fonts behaving differently in web vs figma

Tags: css, next.js, fonts

I have two fonts that are behaving differently in figma vs in the browser. ***Note: I am using the same font files (tusker is `.otf` and helvetica is `.tff`)***

Dev env is just a simple next app (`v 13.2.4`), using local font api to import from font folder (other fonts are working fine btw so I don't believe it's my code)

1. Tusker Grotesk 5800 super font character spacing is different depsite figma not setting a char spacing property (characters are simply `:_`)

**web:**

[image: web]

**figma:**

[image: figma]

2. Helvetica light oblique is incorrect (in web it looks like the regular font style thickness), show in the img below

**left web, right figma:**

[image: left web, right figma]

I tried adding the below after some google searches, which made the fonts look good but no affect on the above

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

Any ideas are welcomed folks! Cheers